# How to avoid damaging SD card for large writes?

Tags: c, embedded, sd-card, fat

Ok, first a little background to help make my question clear:

I am working on a device that collects certain data from sensors and posts them to a server using a GSM modem. As a GSM connection is not 100% reliable, it would contain a logging mechanism that would write unsent data to an SD card.

We are using [Chan's FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) module for providing us with a file system as we want the log to be readable on a PC.

Now I've been testing the FAT system for boundary conditions, i.e., trying to fill up the card completely.

In the first run I opened the file and set the code to keep writing a string until the drive was full. The program would synch after every write.

I left the code running overnight.

The next day, I examined the SD card. I found that the file was only 150 MB in size. There were about 1.2 million lines written to it. The card could still be read from but not written to or formatted.

Next time I tried the same type of test, but this time I used the `f_lseek()` function to pre-allocate the file to 1GB. It would then write to that file until that limit was reached. This time the data would be synced after 50 writes. It would then close that file and open another to do the same.

As you can guess another brave little card lost it's mind that day.

So these are what I would like help with :

1. How to prevent damage to the card while writing large amounts of data?
2. Does leaving the file open for extended periods have any negative effects?

Since the full code may be too long, here's the main part where the writing happens

```
for(file_count=3;file_count>=0;--file_count){

    ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,"===================================");

    ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,file_names[file_count]);


    f_open(&file_ptr,file_names[file_count],FA_WRITE|FA_OPEN_ALWAYS);

    if(result!=FR_OK){

        ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,"\n\rf_open Failed\n\rResult code");
        ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,FRESULT_S[result]);

        continue;

    }

    ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,"\n\rf_open Sucessfull");

    result=f_lseek(&file_ptr,FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_1GB);

    if(result!=FR_OK){

        ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,"\n\rf_lseek Failed for preallocation\n\rResult code");
        ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,FRESULT_S[result]);

        f_close(&file_ptr);

        continue;

    }

    ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,"\n\rf_lseek Sucessfull for preallocation");

    f_lseek(&file_ptr,0);

    bytes_to_write=sizeof(messages[file_count]);

    write_count=0;

    while( (f_tell(&file_ptr) < FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_1GB )){

        result=f_write(&file_ptr,messages[file_count],bytes_to_write,&bytes_written);

        if(result==FR_OK){
            ++write_count;

            if(write_count%50==0){

                f_sync(&file_ptr);
            }

        }else{

            ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,"\n\rWrite failed\n\rFRESULT=");
            ax_log_msg(E_LOG_INFO,FRESULT_S[result]);

            break;

        }

    }

    f_close(&file_ptr);


}
```

Note :

1. ax_log_msg() is part of the device firmware to print on console.
2. FRESULT_S[result] is used to convert the enum result code to a string.

If there is any data missing, please do mention it.

Thank You

Comment: Did you implement HAL functions yourself? (`disk_read`, `disk_write`?) I am presuming you haven't bought the SD card on ebay? :)

Comment: I got the HAL functions as part of the source code of the MSP430 eval board. But they do work.

Comment: The eBay question is actually really important. Did you buy authentic cards from a reputable company? Knock-off cards will die fast. A good 4GB card should be good for many many gigabytes of write endurance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to buffer an entire block of data, perhaps 4 KB, to avoid flashing an entire block with every flush. But, the filesystem or driver should do this for you, as long as you don't call `fflush` explicitly, which is the real lesson.

Why do you need it to be synced so often? Perhaps a timer would work better than an interval per number of records?

Comment: The file system does actually log the data until explicitly synced or until the file pointer is closed.  
  
I do wait for 50 writes before syncing to the file.  
The frequent syncing is because the data being logged is time sensitive and I would like to prevent loss of data due to power loss or some other unexpected factor.

Comment: @SumanRoy It will write the data when it has buffered enough. The buffer can't be that large. You have observed a trade-off between sync frequency and Flash memory longevity, so you need to decide where the optimal balance is.

Comment: Actually the string I used was about 115 bytes, so it would synch after about 5.7 KB of data.

Comment: @SumanRoy That doesn't do you any good if it's not aligned to a block boundary. Both the beginning and the end of a 5.7 KB chunk would be misaligned in a sequence of 4 KB blocks, so most of the time each 5.7 KB flush would require allocation of two blocks, or writing 8 KB of space. I don't know how big the blocks actually are, though. I've done such embedded logging, and I coded directly against the flash controller, very carefully. That's just not possible if you're going through an IDE interface.

Comment: Okay so basically write in chunks of the same size as the sector size of the device. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @SumanRoy What I mean is to either rely on the filesystem and driver, providing the kind of behavior they expect, or research the hardware and directly drive it yourself.

Comment: @SumanRoy are you sure fatfs is caching/buffering the data beyond the SD block size (almost certainly 512B unless you're using a 32GB+ card)? Depending on how fatfs is implemented, you may be hitting the flash for every tiny 115 byte write, but that would be pretty poorly written.

Comment: @rjp Nope. I checked the FatFs documentation. It buffers 512 bytes and then writes it to the card.

Answer (score -2):

Due to 100,000 write cycles limit per sector it is a really challenging task to extend a flash memory lifespan. One of my cards died over one night after I run writing tests on it. I then counted time periods, and that's indeed easy to perform 100,000 writes (in the same sector) just in one night (without taking into account a calculation it comes through experience).

At that time I was told that there is a smart monitors in some filesystems and they count and keep writes number for every sector in order to writings number per every sector was the same, I guess. I neither took nor tested one.

I now found some extremely popular/highly voted answer/suggestion for Raspberrypi and I quote it here now:

These methods should increase the lifespan of the SD card by minimising the number of read/writes in various ways:

### Disable Swap

Swapping is the process of using part of the SD card as volatile memory. This will increase the amount of RAM available, but it will result in a high number of read/writes. It is unlikely to increase performance significantly.

Disable swap with the `swapoff` command:

```
sudo swapoff --all
```

You must also prevent it from coming back after a reboot:

- For Raspbian which uses [dphys-swapfile](http://neil.franklin.ch/Projects/dphys-swapfile/) to manage a swap file (instead of a "normal" swap partition) you can simply `sudo apt-get remove dphys-swapfile` to remove it permanently. Best to remove because setting the `CONF_SWAPSIZE` to 0, as explained in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1605/4387), doesn't seem to work and still creates a 100MB swap file after reboot.
- For other distributions that use a swap partition instead of a swap file, remove the appropriate line from `/etc/fstab`

### Disabling Journaling on the Filesystem

Using a journaling filesystem such as `ext3` or `ext4` WITHOUT a journal is an option to decrease read/writes. The obvious drawback of using a filesystem with journaling disabled is data loss as a result of an ungraceful dismount (i.e. post power failure, kernel lockup, etc.).

You can disable journaling on `ext3` by mounting it as `ext2`

You can disable journaling on `ext4` on an unmounted drive like this:

```
tune4fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdaX
e4fsck –f /dev/sdaX
sudo reboot
```

### The noatime Mount Flag

Assign the noatime mount flag to partitions residing on the SD card by adding it to the options section of the partition in `/etc/fstab`.

> Reading accesses to the file system will no longer result in an update to the atime information associated with the file. The importance of the noatime setting is that it eliminates the need by the system to make writes to the file system for files which are simply being read. Since writes can be somewhat expensive as mentioned in previous section, this can result in measurable performance gains. Note that the write time information to a file will continue to be updated anytime the file is written to with this option enabled.

### Directories in RAM

Highly used directories such as `/var/tmp/` and possibly `/var/log` can be relocated to RAM in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=50M 0 0
```

This will allow `/var/tmp` to use 50MB of RAM as disk space. The only issue with doing this is that any drives mounted in RAM will not persist past a reboot. Thus if you mount `/var/log` and your system encounters an error that causes it to reboot, you will not be able to find out why.

### Directories in external Hard Disk

You can also mount some directories on a persistent USB hard disk. More details of this can be found in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/489/40).

The Raspberry Pi can also boot it's root partition from an external drive. This could be via USB or Ethernet and means that the SD card will only be used to delegate to different device during boot. This requires a bit of kernel hacking to accomplish, as I don't think the default kernel supports USB storage. You can find more information at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/757/40), or this [external blog post](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-root-fs-on-usb-drive/).

---

Here is one more interesting consideration from another answerer:

Excellent article about [flash filesystems](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-flash-filesystems/index.html).

Important question when talking about flash filesystems is following: What is wear leveling? [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling). Basically, on flash disks you can write limited number of times until block goes bad. After that, filesystem (if there is no built-in wear leveling management on hardware, as in case of SSDs there usually is) must mark that block as invalid, and avoid using it anymore.

Typical filesystems (for example reiserfs, ntfs, ext3 and so on) are designed for hard disks, that do not have such limitations.

### JFFS2

Includes compression and elegant wear leveling protection.

### YAFFS2

- Single thing that makes the difference: short mount times, after successful umount.
- Implements write once property: once data is written to one block, there is no need to rewrite it. This is important for protecting against wear leveling.

### LogFS

- Not very mature, but already included in Linux kernel tree.
- Supports larger filesystems than JFFS2/YAFFS2 without problems.

### UBIFS

- More mature than LogFS
- Write caching support
- On scalability: [article](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_scalability). On large disks, better performance than with JFFS2

### ext4

If no driver or card (for example SSD drives do have internal wear leveling, at least usually) handle wear leveling, then ext4 is not the best idea, as it is not intended for raw flash usage.

### What is best one?

Of course, it depends on usage and support. From what I read from the internet, I would recommend UBIFS. Good support for large filesystems, mature development phase, adequate performance and no huge downsides.

Thanks to answerers:

[How can I extend the life of my SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-can-i-extend-the-life-of-my-sd-card)

[Choice of filesystem for GNU/Linux on an SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/248078/choice-of-filesystem-for-gnu-linux-on-an-sd-card)

Comment: Your answer is based more on Pi specifics, but the theory is still helpful.

Comment: Everything in this answer is about Linux. Nothing in the question is about Linux.

Comment: Not all of the advice in this question is even appropriate for a Raspberry Pi. Flash file systems like JFFS2 and the like are intended for use on raw flash devices, not on SD cards.